# Upgrading XCode to 9.1 and iOS Simulator to iOS 11.1 has slowing down Appium-iOS tests drastically

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xcode8, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

Upgrading XCode to 9.1 and iOS Simulator to iOS 11.1 has slowing down Appium-java based tests drastically.

My set-up

- Appium-ide: 1.2.7
- Appium command-line: 1.7.1
- IOS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- XCode: 9.1(9B55)
- iOS Simulator: iOS 11.1

Previously it was as below & tests were running with speed

- XCode: 8.3
- iOS Simulator: iOS 10.3

Comment: I am trying to use network monitoring tool like- Charles Proxy but it hasn't captured requests sent by Appium JSON-Wire protocol.

Comment: If you’re able to take a profile of your tests running in iOS 10.3 (you can download it from Xcode 9’s Preferences rather than using Xcode 8.3) and compare that to your tests running in iOS 11.1, what do the differences show?  Can you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com?

Comment: Hi I was not able to get the logs. But is there any way we could overcome challenge of slowness as its happening with reinstall. Anybody else facing similar issue? Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way of solving your problem without having data that can help determine what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: In below issue (& its link to original facebook webdriveragent team issue) on Appium Webdriver community, we have captured more details: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9842   https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has got resolved using latest version XCode 10, Simulators on latest iOS version 11.4 and using latest Appium runtime 1.8.2-beta from npm. Need to the fresh install of iOS to 11.4 & remove any 11.3 / 11.0 / 10.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

The WebdriverAgent community is still working on providing support for XCode 9, see [this github issue](http://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/639) for details.

In the meantime, we have the following work-around:

- On a test server, install previous version of XCode (i.e. 8.3.3).
- Run this command: `xcode-select --switch /Applications/path to XCode8.3.3/`

For the time being, devs should build their iOS test app to be compatible with XCOde8.3.3.